Responsive img element with srcset
I have the following img element:
  <img
      srcset="https://placehold.co/200x200 200w, https://placehold.co/1000x1000 1000w"
      sizes="(max-width: 600px) 223px, 1000px"
      src="https://placehold.co/1000x1000"
      alt="Dog"
   />

which based on point 3 and 4 from:
3 - Look at the slot size given to that media query.

4 - Load the image referenced in the srcset list that has the same
size as the slot or, if there isn't one, the first image that is
bigger than the chosen slot size.

Since the slot of 223px in sizes doesn't match 200w I would expect the 1000x1000 image being loaded, however that is not happening => https://f4w424.csb.app/. Why is the 200x200 being loaded? The moment I switch from 223px to 224px the 1000x1000 is being loaded. I am confused.
Am I missing something obvious or is the browser doing somtihing behind the scenes?

The following paragraph also says (contradictory I think):

will be loaded, as its inherent width (480w) is closest to the slot
size

That is in the Learn section, in the Docs section it says:

The user agent selects any of the available sources at its discretion.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#srcset

Thank you for this. It is a bit obscure when they say => The user agent selects any of the available sources at its discretion. If I am to implement something like this I would need to know how the browser decides. Maybe I am wrong but I am finding this a little bit strange...
